# Website not coming in Search engine results because of a term

Tags: seo, spellcheck

We have this site which is named Vialogues (Video+Discussion web based application).

```
https://vialogues.com
```

It has been around for some time on the internet and we have also submitted `sitemap.xml` to search engines. However when we search on Google or Bing or Yahoo using the keyword Vialogues, We are given results of the keyword dialogues and this message:

> showing results for dialogues, search instead for vialogues.

I am wondering if it's possible to list the site without the search engine suggesting “showing results for dialogues, search instead for vialogues”?

Answer (score 6):

Search engines such as Bing or Google build spelling correction tables based on usage frequency - your term, Vialogues, both is used too infrequently to be treated as a "possibly-correct" term, and is too close to a highly popular "correct" term, and so is treated as a probable error.

Unfortunately, there's not much you can do here - your choices are to either:

1. Change the name of your site to one that is not similar to a misspelling of a common word
2. Get enough popularity that your term is recognized as a "correct" term

Comment: For an example of the above, try writing "can i has cheezburger" in the search box. I believe google does not suggest a correction in this case because the cheezburger site exists, and is very popular. Also consider how the "v" and "d" keys are near each other in a qwerty keyboard.

Comment: Yes, search engines probably take into account such things as well in their spelling distance metrics

Comment: Better yet, try "can i has zheeaburger" - it corrects to "can i has cheezburger" and even auto-searches for it :)