# Improve SEO for a project that differs from another only by 1 character

Tags: seo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Website not coming in Search engine results because of a term](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8427/website-not-coming-in-search-engine-results-because-of-a-term)

I've somewhat recently forked a popular programming project and am trying to improve search engine visibility. The major issue I'm having though is that the name is so similar to the origional project name: I just took it and slapped an X on the end of it.

The issue is that whenever I google for the project, Google always says "Showing results for project. Search instead for projectX". I do think this is hurting me as Google sees my project as a misspelling or something completely unrelated. People have to really search for my project to find it.

Is there any way I can tell google or other search engines that my project fork is not a misspelling of the original project?